# Translucent Status Bar

Tags: ios, ios5, statusbar

My iPhone app (iOS 5.0 or later) has a translucent status bar. Upon first launch it shows the splash screen and then during the rest of the lifetime of the app, the splash screen is shown through the status bar. It's a nice little detail that seems to work, visually, and is pleasing.

However, after having received a call to

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {}
```

All of a sudden the desktop is showing through in the status bar. Does anybody have an idea why this happens and what I could do to prevent this?